# ICal cannot read .ics file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, icalendar

I am using the DDay.iCal library to create .ics files for importing into iCal on iPhones, iPads, and Macs. I have been able to create the file just fine, however when I try to import it into iCal on any of the devices above, I get the Generic error "iCal cannot read this file, no events were added to your calendar."

Here is the contents of the .ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:Local Ruckus 04508292-17ee-4721-ab6d-f6ea49f972d0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:Our Miller Lite Hot Country Nights concert series presented by 
 Q104 is back for its 5th year!Shows begin around 7pm. Get here early to cl
 aim your spot! Free and open to public of all ages. Under 21s MUST be acco
 mpanied by a legal guardian and must arrive before 9pm. Venue is 21+ after
 9pm.
DTEND:20120823T230000
DTSTAMP:20120823T213408Z
DTSTART:20120823T190000
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Hot Country Nights Concert Series
UID:de56c779-63c0-4dc5-b532-4b5a1d31f5ec
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with this file?

Thanks